# How can I fit this question about class into the site remit?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is there anything analogous to the withdrawal of labour in a mass strike, on the internet? Obviously, Marxists [talk](http://www.historicalmaterialism.org/node/963) about the internet. And e,g. this paper I haven't read (I lack library access) on internet studies, by the same linked to author (Fuchs)

> [The paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1461444812462854) provides a literature overview for showing that, and how,
>   Marxian concepts have been used in Internet Studies. Internet Studies
>   to a certain extent analyse the Internet, economy and society in
>   Marxist-inspired studies terms, yet do not acknowledge the connection
>   to Marx and thus seem superficial in their various approaches
>   discussing capitalism, exploitation and domination.

But I wondered if, given that work place agitation will presumably remain low key in the foreseeable future, what emancipatory potentials there are to how we use the internet. Specifically ones pitting the proletariat directly against the ruling class, and ones that raise class consciousness.

---

I'm asking just because I believe I have a good answer for it. Surely class consciousness exists in the struggle to be permitted class consciousness at work. The internet would shift that into, I think, on one hand greater penetration into the worker's life, and, on the other, that existing as an action and not mere consciousness at a more local level; pockets of communists?

Comment: Another problem we have at SE is the lack of Marxian educated members. I mean educated through 2019. Not like me who failed to update after the early 1980s. When we get questions on Marx here most of them seem a bit outdated. My opinion. So you can ask a question, you may not get good answers at the present time.

Comment: yeah i'm not a great marxist @Gordon familiar with it that's all really. cheers for commmenting

Comment: not read anything of haffner!

Comment: YW, I am sure there are more scholarly treatments of the period today, but you can't beat Haffner for readability and it's free!